# Append to list in python results in None type object

Tags: python

For the following list[int]:

```
In [112]: text = [1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,4,5,22,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,3]
```

Let us append an int:

```
In [115]: next_char = 4
In [113]:  y = text[1:].append(next_char)
```

What is the result?

```
In [114]: type(y)
Out[114]: NoneType
```

Why is it None?

**Update**  Presuming that the list.append() returned None, I had also tried

```
text.append(next_char)
```

but `text` remained unchanged .. I will double check if that behavior were *consistent* (or if in fact I ended up with a corner case on usage of append()) ..

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None`... Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @JeffMercado  The original list remained untouched when running list.append() (without assignment to a var) so then .. where is the updated list?

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling `text[1:].append(next_char)`... it should be `text.append(next_char)` and it doesn't return anything because it changes the list in place.

Comment: @Suever  Your comment and my own self-answer occurred simultaneously.  I need the text[1:] but it needs to be separate variable.

Comment: About the "mark as duplicate" :  this question embeds more in it (the internal assignment to a variable) then the other one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is a combination of two things:

```
The list.append() returns None
The appended list no longer exists since the list[1:] was appended to.
```

So the correct code is:

```
y = text[1:]
y.append(next_char)
```

they need to be in two separate commands.

```
In [120]: y
Out[120]: [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 22, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`append` changes the list in place and returns `None`. By indexing the list first, you are creating a copy of it. I.e., you are appending to a copy to which you no longer have access and the original list remains unchanged.

Appending to text without indexing will modify the list.

Comment: I had realized/answered this just before you added this

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` is an In-Place-modification of list and returns `None` as a Value.

This means you assign `None` to y.

EDIT: The same principal applies to other In-Place-modifiers (`.sort()` ,...)

Comment: True .. but more complete answers were already in place.